# SonataAdmin setSubClasses removes a letter from the entity name

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata

When I try to use the argument setSubClasses in my services definition, the name of the subclass added to the Admin has a letter removed

Here's my definition

```
sonata.admin.question:
    class: Hippy\ScavengerHuntBundle\Admin\QuestionAdmin
    tags:
        - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: "Questions", label: "Question" }
    arguments:
        - ~
        - Hippy\ScavengerHuntBundle\Entity\Question
        - ~
    calls:
        - [ setTranslationDomain, [HippyScavengerHuntBundle]]
        - [ setSubClasses, [{lettersInOrderQuestion : "Hippy\ScavengerHuntBundle\Entity\LettersInOrderQuestion"}]]
```

In my admin class, under the configureFormFields method, I put the following line and the result was quite surprising:

```
var_dump($this->getSubClasses());
```

The result:

```
array (size=1)
  'lettersInOrderQuestion' => string 'Hippy\ScavengerHuntBundle\Entity ettersInOrderQuestion' (length=56)
```

It looks like the "\L" got removed somehow... normally, it would be `Entity\LettersInOrderQuestion` not `EntityettersInOrderQuestion`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't put your namespace around the namespace. Therefore, you should write the following :

```
{lettersInOrderQuestion : Hippy\ScavengerHuntBundle\Entity\LettersInOrderQuestion}
```